# How to make an iframe or JS embedded form from Wufoo scroll to the top after button click?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe

On the third page of my embedded form, the content is much shorter than the other 2 pages, so when a user navigates to the third page it appears at the bottom and anyone filling it out has to scroll up to the top to finish the final page.

I tried embedding the form with JS, HTML & using the WordPress plugin w/shortcode, but none seem to work. I have also seen one other post like this on SO but it wasn't specific enough to my problem and I don't know enough JS to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.